# how to calculate row size of an unstructured data?

Tags: database, size, row, storage

In classical RDBMS it' relatively easy to calculate maximum row size by adding max size of each field defined within a table. This value multiplied by predicted number of rows will give max table size excluding indexes, logs etc.

Today in the era of structured way of storing unstructured data it's relatively hard to tell what will be the optimal table size.

Is there any way to calculate or predict table or even database growth and storage requirements without sample data load ?

What are your ways of calculating row size and planning storage capacity for unstructured database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much the same. Find the average size of data you need to persist and multiply it with your estimated transaction count per time unit.

Database engines may allocate datafile chunks exponentially (first 16mb then 32mb etc.) so you need to know about the workings of your dbms engine to translate the data size to physical storage space size.